# How to make drop down menu from web2py database

Tags: html, database, menu, web2py

I'm trying to populate a drop down navigation bar from a web2py database of product names. The table is defined in db.py like so:

```
db.define_table('product',
Field('prodid', unique=True),
Field('name'),
Field('stock', 'integer'))
```

I've done a bit of research and found heaps of ways to do it with PHP from an SQL database but I haven't been able to find anything about retrieving from a local database in web2py.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
{{ rows = db().select(db.product.ALL) }}
{{if len(rows):}}
<ul>
{{ for r in rows: }}
  <li>
    <a href="yourlink/{{=r.id}}">
        {{=r.name}}
    </a>
  </li>
{{pass}}
</ul>
{{pass}}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the code that the wizard comes up with (with a tweak in the 'format'):

```
########################################
db.define_table('t_products',
    Field('f_prodid', type='string',
          label=T('Prodid')),
    Field('f_name', type='string',
          label=T('Name')),
    Field('f_stock', type='string',
          label=T('Stock')),
    format='%(f_name)s',
    migrate=settings.migrate)


########################################
db.define_table('t_orders',
    Field('f_orderid', type='string',
          label=T('Orderid')),
    Field('f_product_name', type='reference t_products',
          label=T('Product Name')),
    format='%(f_orderid)s',
    migrate=settings.migrate)
```

The key words are 'reference' in the second table and the 'format' in the first one.

Comment: so if im correct settings.migrate allows me to access this table as an sql table using php correct? or am i looking at this all wrong?

Comment: AFAIK settings.migrate takes care of the changes in the model, which is not mandatory for this example. If you created the DB let's say in a mysql server (default web2py DB is sqlite), then you can access the same database from php (although I wouldn't know why you would do that).

Comment: well i need to retrieve the product names one at a time in order to populate a drop down menu in the html file. What would you recommend to be the best way to do that?

Comment: this would be:`{{rows = db().select(db.t_products.ALL)}}
<select>
{{for row in rows:}}<option>{{=row.f_name}}</option>{{pass}}
</select>` somewhere in the html file.